# DataGrid throws InvalidOperationException by Scrolling

Tags: wpf, exception, datagrid, scroll, invalidoperationexception

I want to show in a DataGrid the contents of a file. (The file contains more than 200,000 lines)

To show the Grid with the Data is fast.

But when I use the Scrollbar (for down scrolling) I've got the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
{"An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.\n  See the inner exception for more information."}
```

InnerException:

```
Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):
This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:0' with name '(unnamed)' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
  Accumulated count 0 is different from actual count 200000.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

One or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:
     System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator
      System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection
       System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView
        System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WpfApplication3.Entry, WpfApplication3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
(The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)

The most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with an incorrect index or item parameter.

The exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this is to run a command similar to the following:
   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator, System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)
from the Immediate window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.
```

The Exception tells that it: "has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection."

Thats the code:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="Test">
        <WpfApplication3:Viewer x:Name="LogUC" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Test.DataContext = this;

        LogUC.Loaded += LogUcOnLoaded;
    }

    private void LogUcOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        LogUC.Test();
    }
}
```

**Viewer.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.Viewer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Name="Container">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EntryCollection, Mode=OneTime}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                  CanUserResizeRows="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ErrorCode}" Header="" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Time}" Header="Time" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Content}" Header="Content" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Viewer.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Viewer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Viewer()
    {
        EntryCollection = new List<Entry>();
        InitializeComponent();
        Container.DataContext = this;
    }

    public List<Entry> EntryCollection { get; set; }

    internal void Test()
    {
        List<Entry> test = new List<Entry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
        {
            Entry entry = new Entry(){
                ErrorCode = 0,
                Time = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                Content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
            };
            test.Add(entry);
        }

        EntryCollection.AddRange(test);
        OnPropertyChanged("EntryCollection");
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

**Entry.cs**

```
public class Entry
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }

    public string Time { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this happens, but I can tell you how to make it work.

It looks like you are never telling the DataGrid that the items in EntryCollection have changed, by raising an appropriate event.

The `OnPropertyChanged("EntryCollection")` call you have in the `Test` method has no effect, since you have `Mode=OneTime` on the DataGrid binding, and since the `EntryCollection` object is a `List`and not a `ObservableCollection`, the adding of items to it is not raising any events to notify the DataGrid.

The way I see it, you can do two things to fix this.

1. Make `EntryCollection` an `ObservableCollection` so the DataGrid is notified as items are added/removed. Then you can remove the `OnPropertyChanged` call, and still have `Mode=OneTime`.

   ```
   public Viewer()
   {
       EntryCollection = new ObservableCollection<Entry>();
       InitializeComponent();
       Container.DataContext = this;
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Entry> EntryCollection { get; set; }

   internal void Test()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
       {
           Entry entry = new Entry()
           {
               ErrorCode = 0,
               Time = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
               Content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
           };

           EntryCollection.Add(entry);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Instead of adding items to `EntryCollection`, set it to a new instance and raise the `PropertyChanged` event. Doing it that way, you need to remove the `Mode=OneTime` setting in the XAML.

   ```
   public Viewer()
   {
       EntryCollection = new List<Entry>();    
       InitializeComponent();
       Container.DataContext = this;
   }

   public List<Entry> EntryCollection { get; set; }

   internal void Test()
   {
       List<Entry> test = new List<Entry>();

       for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
       {
           Entry entry = new Entry()
           {
               ErrorCode = 0,
               Time = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
               Content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
           };
           test.Add(entry);    
       }

       EntryCollection = test;
       OnPropertyChanged("EntryCollection");
   }
   ```